# ManyToManyField "table exist" error on syncdb

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, many-to-many

When I include a `ModelToModelField` to one of my models the following error is thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 362, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 93, in handle_noargs
    cursor.execute(statement)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 19, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 84, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in execute
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'orders_proof_approved_associations' already exists")
```

Field definition:

```
proof_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.FILE_UPLOAD_ROOT)

class Proof(mixins.ModifiedDates):
"""
Each Order eventually has a Proof or multiple rounds of Proofs. Required are a proof file and
a Record Set file containing the records used for the proof.
"""
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    proof_count = int(Proof.objects.filter(order=instance.order).count()) + 1

    destination_path = os.path.join(instance.order.ATTACHMENTS_RELATIVE_ROOT, 'proofs')

    return os.path.join(destination_path, '%02d_%s' % (proof_count, filename))

file = models.FileField(storage=proof_storage, upload_to=get_upload_path)
approved = models.BooleanField(default=0)
order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
record_set_file = models.FileField(storage=proof_storage, upload_to=get_upload_path)
approved_associations = models.ManyToManyField(Association)
```

Everything works fine when I remove the field, and the table is no where in sight.

Any thoughts as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was trying too hard to get django to do what I wanted.

I had two apps with a common name. Obviously a big no-no, but I had them organized in to subapps `subapp1.appname` and `subapp2.appname`. Anyway when it comes down to it Django only cares about the appname*, and when I ran syncdb it came across both apps in my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and tried to install the m2m model twice. Anyway, solved by renaming one of the apps (funny enough to a more well suited name).

```
* In Django 1.2 there is better support for `app_labels` 
  which can be used instead of the app name when referencing.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass the `db_table` option to a ManyToManyField to step around the default table name created/used by Django. See the [documentation here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.db_table).

However, you should not be seeing an error like this. If you could post your models code, we may be able to help better.

Comment: Tried it with the `db_table` arg, but same problem. The error message reads with the new table name, but that's the only difference. Will post the model code above.